# With GDPR, can you request 'real life data' be deleted/forgotten?

Tags: gdpr

For example, can you request libraries remove your name from books you have checked out?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe GDPR makes a distinction between 'real life' and 'online'. It's all real life.

You can tell anyone that they don't have consent to keep your personal data, but that doesn't mean they always have to delete it. There are six lawful bases for processing of personal data, so if an organisation is using and can justify one other than consent then they don't necessarily have to delete your data when they ask. The six bases are listed by the UK Information Commissioner's Office:

> (a) Consent: the individual has given clear consent for you to
>   process their personal data for a specific purpose.
>
> (b) Contract: the processing is necessary for a contract you have with
>   the individual, or because they have asked you to take specific steps
>   before entering into a contract.
>
> (c) Legal obligation: the processing is necessary for you to comply
>   with the law (not including contractual obligations).
>
> (d) Vital interests: the processing is necessary to protect someone’s
>   life.
>
> (e) Public task: the processing is necessary for you to perform a task
>   in the public interest or for your official functions, and the task or
>   function has a clear basis in law.
>
> (f) Legitimate interests: the processing is necessary for your
>   legitimate interests or the legitimate interests of a third party
>   unless there is a good reason to protect the individual’s personal
>   data which overrides those legitimate interests. (This cannot apply if
>   you are a public authority processing data to perform your official
>   tasks.)

https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/lawful-basis-for-processing/#ib3

Comment: I don't think this answers the question of, Can you ask libraries to remove your name from the books you've checked out in the past?

Comment: That was just given as an example by the OP. The general answer is you can always ask but whether the organisation has to delete the data depends on the specifics of the situation.